# State parameter not being passed

Tags: react-native

I iterate over a [list](https://www.koolbusiness.com/in.json) and try to pass the `id` parameter with each element and link to a details screen:

```
_renderList = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={(event) => this._selectedItem(item.key)}>
            <View  style={styles.listRowContainer}>
                <View  style={styles.listinside1Container}>
                    <Image  style={styles.listImage} source={item.icon} />
                    <View  style={styles.listContainer} onPress={(event) => this._selectedItem(item.text)}  >
                        <Text  onPress={ ()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('FontsTab', { id: item.id }) } style={styles.listHeader} >
                            {item.title}
                        </Text>
                        <Text  style={styles.listValue} >{item.value}</Text>
                        <Image 
                            style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
                            source={{uri: item.img}}
                        />

                    </View>
                </View>

                            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );

}
```

In the details screen I try to read the `id` parameters but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

The code where I try to read it is:

```
getNavigationParams() {
    return this.props.navigation.state.params || {}
}
```

The error I get

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state.params.id')

This error is located at:
    in Fonts (at fonts.js:12)
    in FontsTabView (at SceneView.js:17)
    in SceneView (at CardStack.js:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at CardStack.js:454)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at CardStack.js:453)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:147)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Card.js:12)
    in Card (at PointerEventsContainer.js:39)
    in Container (at CardStack.js:498)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at CardStack.js:414)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at CardStack.js:413)
    in CardStack (at CardStackTransitioner.js:67)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at Transitioner.js:142)
    in Transitioner (at CardStackTransitioner.js:19)
    in CardStackTransitioner (at StackNavigator.js:41)
    in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:13)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:226)
    in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:17)
    in SceneView (at ResourceSavingSceneView.js:55)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at ResourceSavingSceneView.js:48)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at ResourceSavingSceneView.js:39)
    in ResourceSavingSceneView (at TabView.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (created by ViewPagerAndroid)
    in AndroidViewPager (at ViewPagerAndroid.android.js:238)
    in ViewPagerAndroid (at TabViewPagerAndroid.js:127)
    in TabViewPagerAndroid (at TabViewAnimated.js:71)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at TabViewAnimated.js:194)
    in TabViewAnimated (at TabView.js:192)
    in TabView (at withCachedChildNavigation.js:69)
    in withCachedChildNavigation(TabView) (at TabNavigator.js:34)
    in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:13)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:226)
    in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:17)
    in SceneView (at DrawerScreen.js:21)
    in DrawerScreen (at withCachedChildNavigation.js:69)
    in withCachedChildNavigation(DrawerScreen) (at DrawerNavigator.js:71)
    in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:13)
    in Navigator (at DrawerView.js:178)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at DrawerLayoutAndroid.android.js:186)
    in AndroidDrawerLayout (at DrawerLayoutAndroid.android.js:200)
    in DrawerLayoutAndroid (at DrawerView.js:158)
    in DrawerView (at DrawerNavigator.js:88)
    in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:13)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:226)
    in NavigationContainer (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
render
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\src\views\fonts_home.js:360:79
proxiedMethod
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-proxy\modules\createPrototypeProxy.js:44:35
finishClassComponent
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8707:21
updateClassComponent
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8675:6
beginWork
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:9376:10
performUnitOfWork
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11771:25
workLoop
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11839:43
invokeGuardedCallback
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:39:15
invokeGuardedCallback
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:221:34
renderRoot
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11925:30
performWorkOnRoot
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12742:34
performWork
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12660:26
performSyncWork
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12622:16
requestWork
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12535:6
scheduleWorkImpl
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12374:22
scheduleWork
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12321:28
enqueueSetState
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:6388:19
setState
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:241:31
<unknown>
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\src\views\fonts_home.js:336:30
tryCallOne
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14
<unknown>
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25
<unknown>
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:297:23
_callTimer
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:154:6
_callImmediatesPass
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:202:17
callImmediates
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:466:11
__callImmediates
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:329:4
<unknown>
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:147:6
__guardSafe
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:316:6
flushedQueue
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:146:17
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
    C:\Users\datan\react-native-init\koolbusiness\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:142:11
```

Details

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    ScrollView,
    StyleSheet,
    Platform,
    Image,
    TouchableHighlight, ListView,ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';

import { Text, Card, Divider, Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

const iOS_fonts = [
  'Academy Engraved LET',
  'AcademyEngravedLetPlain',
  'Al Nile',
  'AlNile-Bold',
  'American Typewriter',
  'AmericanTypewriter-Bold',
  'AmericanTypewriter-Condensed',
  'AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold',
  'AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight',
  'AmericanTypewriter-Light',
  'Apple Color Emoji',
  'AppleColorEmoji',
  'Apple SD Gothic Neo',
  'AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold',
  'AppleSDGothicNeo-Light',
  'AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium',
  'AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular',
  'AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold',
  'AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin',
  'AppleSDGothicNeo-UltraLight',
  'Arial',
  'Arial Hebrew',
  'Arial Rounded MT Bold',
  'Arial-BoldItalicMT',
  'Arial-BoldMT',
  'Arial-ItalicMT',
  'ArialHebrew',
  'ArialHebrew-Bold',
  'ArialHebrew-Light',
  'ArialMT',
  'ArialRoundedMTBold',
  'Avenir',
  'Avenir-Black',
  'Avenir-BlackOblique',
  'Avenir-Book',
  'Avenir-BookOblique',
  'Avenir-Heavy',
  'Avenir-HeavyOblique',
  'Avenir-Light',
  'Avenir-LightOblique',
  'Avenir-Medium',
  'Avenir-MediumOblique',
  'Avenir-Oblique',
  'Avenir-Roman',
  'Avenir Next',
  'Avenir Next Condensed',
  'AvenirNext-Bold',
  'AvenirNext-BoldItalic',
  'AvenirNext-DemiBold',
  'AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic',
  'AvenirNext-Heavy',
  'AvenirNext-HeavyItalic',
  'AvenirNext-Italic',
  'AvenirNext-Medium',
  'AvenirNext-MediumItalic',
  'AvenirNext-Regular',
  'AvenirNext-UltraLight',
  'AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic',
  'AvenirNextCondensed-Bold',
  'AvenirNextCondensed-BoldItalic',
  'AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBold',
  'AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic',
  'AvenirNextCondensed-Heavy',
  'AvenirNextCondensed-HeavyItalic',
  'AvenirNextCondensed-Italic',
  'AvenirNextCondensed-Medium',
  'AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic',
  'AvenirNextCondensed-Regular',
  'AvenirNextCondensed-UltraLight',
  'AvenirNextCondensed-UltraLightItalic',
  'Bangla Sangam MN',
  'Baskerville',
  'Baskerville-Bold',
  'Baskerville-BoldItalic',
  'Baskerville-Italic',
  'Baskerville-SemiBold',
  'Baskerville-SemiBoldItalic',
  'Bodoni 72',
  'Bodoni 72 Oldstyle',
  'Bodoni 72 Smallcaps',
  'Bodoni Ornaments',
  'BodoniOrnamentsITCTT',
  'BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-Bold',
  'BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-Book',
  'BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-BookIta',
  'BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-Bold',
  'BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-Book',
  'BodoniSvtyTwoSCITCTT-Book',
  'Bradley Hand',
  'BradleyHandITCTT-Bold',
  'Chalkboard SE',
  'ChalkboardSE-Bold',
  'ChalkboardSE-Light',
  'ChalkboardSE-Regular',
  'Chalkduster',
  'Cochin',
  'Cochin-Bold',
  'Cochin-BoldItalic',
  'Cochin-Italic',
  'Copperplate',
  'Copperplate-Bold',
  'Copperplate-Light',
  'Courier',
  'Courier New',
  'Courier-Bold',
  'Courier-BoldOblique',
  'Courier-Oblique',
  'CourierNewPS-BoldItalicMT',
  'CourierNewPS-BoldMT',
  'CourierNewPS-ItalicMT',
  'CourierNewPSMT',
  'Damascus',
  'DamascusBold',
  'DamascusLight',
  'DamascusMedium',
  'DamascusSemiBold',
  'Devanagari Sangam MN',
  'DevanagariSangamMN',
  'DevanagariSangamMN-Bold',
  'Didot',
  'Didot-Bold',
  'Didot-Italic',
  'DiwanMishafi',
  'Euphemia UCAS',
  'EuphemiaUCAS-Bold',
  'EuphemiaUCAS-Italic',
  'Farah',
  'Futura',
  'Futura-CondensedExtraBold',
  'Futura-CondensedMedium',
  'Futura-Medium',
  'Futura-MediumItalic',
  'Geeza Pro',
  'GeezaPro-Bold',
  'Georgia',
  'Georgia-Bold',
  'Georgia-BoldItalic',
  'Georgia-Italic',
  'Gill Sans',
  'GillSans-Bold',
  'GillSans-BoldItalic',
  'GillSans-Italic',
  'GillSans-Light',
  'GillSans-LightItalic',
  'GillSans-SemiBold',
  'GillSans-SemiBoldItalic',
  'GillSans-UltraBold',
  'Gujarati Sangam MN',
  'GujaratiSangamMN',
  'GujaratiSangamMN-Bold',
  'Gurmukhi MN',
  'GurmukhiMN-Bold',
  'Heiti SC',
  'Heiti TC',
  'Helvetica',
  'Helvetica Neue',
  'Helvetica-Bold',
  'Helvetica-BoldOblique',
  'Helvetica-Light',
  'Helvetica-LightOblique',
  'Helvetica-Oblique',
  'HelveticaNeue-Bold',
  'HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic',
  'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack',
  'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold',
  'HelveticaNeue-Italic',
  'HelveticaNeue-Light',
  'HelveticaNeue-LightItalic',
  'HelveticaNeue-Medium',
  'HelveticaNeue-MediumItalic',
  'HelveticaNeue-Thin',
  'HelveticaNeue-ThinItalic',
  'HelveticaNeue-UltraLight',
  'HelveticaNeue-UltraLightItalic',
  'Hiragino Mincho ProN',
  'Hiragino Sans',
  'HiraginoSans-W3',
  'HiraginoSans-W6',
  'HiraMinProN-W3',
  'HiraMinProN-W6',
  'Hoefler Text',
  'HoeflerText-Black',
  'HoeflerText-BlackItalic',
  'HoeflerText-Italic',
  'HoeflerText-Regular',
  'Kailasa',
  'Kailasa-Bold',
  'Kannada Sangam MN',
  'KannadaSangamMN',
  'KannadaSangamMN-Bold',
  'Khmer Sangam MN',
  'Kohinoor Bangla',
  'Kohinoor Devanagari',
  'Kohinoor Telugu',
  'KohinoorBangla-Light',
  'KohinoorBangla-Regular',
  'KohinoorBangla-Semibold',
  'KohinoorDevanagari-Light',
  'KohinoorDevanagari-Regular',
  'KohinoorDevanagari-Semibold',
  'KohinoorTelugu-Light',
  'KohinoorTelugu-Medium',
  'KohinoorTelugu-Regular',
  'Lao Sangam MN',
  'Malayalam Sangam MN',
  'MalayalamSangamMN',
  'MalayalamSangamMN-Bold',
  'Marker Felt',
  'MarkerFelt-Thin',
  'MarkerFelt-Wide',
  'Menlo',
  'Menlo-Bold',
  'Menlo-BoldItalic',
  'Menlo-Italic',
  'Menlo-Regular',
  'Mishafi',
  'Noteworthy',
  'Noteworthy-Bold',
  'Noteworthy-Light',
  'Optima',
  'Optima-Bold',
  'Optima-BoldItalic',
  'Optima-ExtraBlack',
  'Optima-Italic',
  'Optima-Regular',
  'Oriya Sangam MN',
  'OriyaSangamMN',
  'OriyaSangamMN-Bold',
  'Palatino',
  'Palatino-Bold',
  'Palatino-BoldItalic',
  'Palatino-Italic',
  'Palatino-Roman',
  'Papyrus',
  'Papyrus-Condensed',
  'Party LET',
  'PartyLetPlain',
  'PingFang HK',
  'PingFang SC',
  'PingFang TC',
  'PingFangHK-Light',
  'PingFangHK-Medium',
  'PingFangHK-Regular',
  'PingFangHK-Semibold',
  'PingFangHK-Thin',
  'PingFangHK-Ultralight',
  'PingFangSC-Light',
  'PingFangSC-Medium',
  'PingFangSC-Regular',
  'PingFangSC-Semibold',
  'PingFangSC-Thin',
  'PingFangSC-Ultralight',
  'PingFangTC-Light',
  'PingFangTC-Medium',
  'PingFangTC-Regular',
  'PingFangTC-Semibold',
  'PingFangTC-Thin',
  'PingFangTC-Ultralight',
  'Savoye LET',
  'SavoyeLetPlain',
  'Sinhala Sangam MN',
  'SinhalaSangamMN',
  'SinhalaSangamMN-Bold',
  'Snell Roundhand',
  'SnellRoundhand-Black',
  'SnellRoundhand-Bold',
  'Symbol',
  'Tamil Sangam MN',
  'TamilSangamMN-Bold',
  'Telugu Sangam MN',
  'Thonburi',
  'Thonburi-Bold',
  'Thonburi-Light',
  'Times New Roman',
  'TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT',
  'TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT',
  'TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT',
  'TimesNewRomanPSMT',
  'Trebuchet MS',
  'Trebuchet-BoldItalic',
  'TrebuchetMS-Bold',
  'TrebuchetMS-Italic',
  'Verdana',
  'Verdana-Bold',
  'Verdana-BoldItalic',
  'Verdana-Italic',
  'Zapf Dingbats',
  'ZapfDingbatsITC',
  'Zapfino',
];

const android_fonts = [
  'normal',
  'notoserif',
  'sans-serif',
  'sans-serif-light',
  'sans-serif-thin',
  'sans-serif-condensed',
  'sans-serif-medium',
  'serif',
  'Roboto',
  'monospace',
];

class Fonts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataSource: null,
            isLoading: true
        };
    }
    getNavigationParams() {
        return this.props.navigation.state.params || {}
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        return fetch('http://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/4580715507220480.json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson,
                }, function(){

                });

            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
  render() {
      if(this.state.isLoading){
          return(
              <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
                  <ActivityIndicator/>
              </View>
          )
      }
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          <Image
              style={{width: 150, height: 150}}
              source={{uri: this.state.dataSource.img}}
          />
          <Text  style={styles.listValue} >{this.state.dataSource.text}</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default Fonts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `onPress` on the `<Text`> element. It should be on the `<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ ()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('FontsTab', { id: item.id }) } style={styles.listHeader} >`

Comment: But how do I access it in the second screen? `this.props.navigation.state.params.id` is not working.

Comment: All screens used in react-navigation should have the prop `navigation` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html. Can you post your  detailed screen code fully?

Comment: I posted the code from the second screen in the question. It seems that the `id` parameter is not being passed.

Comment: Where is getNavigationParams function being called?

Comment: getNavigationParams always returned null. I was going to use it to return the id of the element for the fetch part: `fetch('http://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/'+this.getNavigationParams().id+'.json')` but that didn't work.

Comment: Probably the params a bit later after mounting. I guess you already debugged this.props.navigation in render or before to check if it is the not case though?

Comment: ok. For time being, you can make a quick check add this `<Text> JSON.stringify(this.props.navigation)</Text>` in your detailed screen inside `<ScrollView>`

Comment: Np. What fixed it?

Comment: I had to put the class in the right StackNavigator. I had the class in the wrong StackNavigator.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz,  @agent_hunt: `<Text>` element does indeed have an `onPress`. There is no need to wrap it inside a `TouchableWithoutFeedback`.

Here is the link to the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#onpress

Comment: @flaky I'm back here trying to figure out what happened. I need to do things the right way and I didn't. I broke some other route doing my changes so I had to revert.